# GetType() Shows non-existent type?

Tags: vb.net

As I am trying to figure out how to work with the Siemens Tia Portal Openness framework, I try to find an item in my Tia Portal project with the `ControllerTarget` type.

I try to find the items like this:

```
Imports Siemens.Engineering
Imports Siemens.Engineering.HW

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim myTiaPortal
    myTiaPortal = New TiaPortal(TiaPortalMode.WithoutUserInterface)

    'The portal is open, now create a project.
    Dim tiaProject As Project

    'Open the sample project:
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = "C:\Path\To\Project\Sample_Project.ap13"
    tiaProject = myTiaPortal.Projects.Open(fileName)

    'Get the frist device from the project:
    Dim tiaDevice As Device
    tiaDevice = tiaProject.Devices.First

    For Each item As IDeviceItem In tiaDevice.DeviceItems
        Console.WriteLine(item.GetType())
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

End Module
```

This shows two items in the project:

```
Siemens.Engineering.HW.DeviceItemImplementation
Siemens.Engineering.HW.ControllerTargetImplementation
```

When I try to define an object of the type `ControllerTargetImplementation` I get the message that this datatype does not exist.

When I try to convert the item of type `ControllerTargetImplementation` to an object of type `ControllerTarget`, this seems to work perfectly.

Does this mean that the type returned by `GetType()` does not have to be the same as the actual type of the object? Is this normal? Or is this a strange thing in the openness platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I try to define an object of the type `ControllerTargetImplementation` I get the message that this datatype does not exist.

Types can be internal to an assembly, which means that while they exist and things like `GetType` will show them to be there, you can't use them directly.

> When I try to convert the item of type `ControllerTargetImplementation` to an object of type `ControllerTarget`, this seems to work perfectly.

Given the names involved here, it certainly sounds like `ControllerTarget` is the type being exposed to you, the consumer of the library, while the implementation of that type, perhaps a subclass or an implementation of an interface (ie is `ControllerTarget` a class or interface?) is hidden from you as you don't need to know about how it does it's job, nor interfere with it.

> Does this mean that the type returned by `GetType()` does not have to be the same as the actual type of the object?

The actual type of the object is what is reported by `GetType`, but that doesn't mean that it's necessarily what you refer to it as.  For instance, consider the following:

```
Class A

End Class

Class B
Inherits A

End Class

Sub Main
    Dim obj as A = new B()
    Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType())
End Sub
```

This will report `obj` as having a type of `B` (because that's the actual type we instantiated with `new B()`), even though it's stored against a variable of type `A`.